# Why is the letter "w" not pronounced "double v"?

Tags: alphabet

Was "w" written with smoother curves back then?

Comment: As Elliott has already answered that U and V were the same in Latin, I'll just add that the French went the other way after the split: they *do* pronounce 'W' as double-V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The letter "u" was written like a "v".

From [here](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/latin.htm),

> **Roman alphabet for Latin**
>
> The Romans used just 23 letters to write Latin:

[image: Roman alphabet for Latin]